# JQuery code not working on Joomla install

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

This JQuery code to pop up an alert when a href is clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/fuYLX/11/

Is not working on my Joomla 3.2 install: http://www.dasa.org.uk.gridhosted.co.uk/registration

Can anyone help me to work out why please?

Here is the Jfiddle HTML code:

```
<div id="stepbystep" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"> <a href="#step-1">
        <span>Step 1</span>
      </a>

        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"> <a href="#step-2">
        <span>Step 2</span>
      </a>

        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"> <a href="#step-3">
        <span>Step 3</span>
      </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var tabCheck = {
  ready : function() {
    jQuery('#stepbystep ul li a').click(
      function(e) {
        alert('hi');
      }
    );
  }
};

$(document).ready(tabCheck.ready);
```

Comment: Where are you adding this Javascript to and how are you adding it? Are you simply using `<script>` tags or are you using Joomla's `addScriptDeclaration()`. It might also be due to the fact that you have 2 versions of jQuery being imported and thus causing conflicts

Comment: It's just added within the `<script>` tags.  Other jquery code within the same tags is working and the jquery library is only imported once.

Comment: I have checked your site using Firebug and did a search for `tabCheck` and it wasn't found. I don't think your JS is being injected

Comment: The code is definitely there - it can be seen by viewing the page source. (Currently tabCheck isn't there because I am trying Brian Bolli's code from his answer below.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there's an error regarding your selector string.  This error appeared in console when I navigated to the link you sent.

```
[jquery.form] terminating; zero elements found by selector
```

On first glance it appears the selector is correct, so my thought is this is tied to the DOM elements not being available when the script is loaded and run.  Try changing your JS to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#stepbystep ul li a', function(e) {
    alert('hi');
});
```

or, if you want to continue to follow your existing paradigm:

```
$(document).on('click', '#stepbystep ul li a', function(e) {
    tabCheck.ready;
});
```

*** EDIT 1 ***

Try wrapping your JavaScript code in a IIFE like so:

```
(function($) {

    // code here

})(jQuery);
```

Not 100% if that is what's causing the 'not a function' error, but this will at least eliminate conflicts with the mootools library.  This immediately invoked function takes in the non-conflicting jQuery object library, and allows you to use the $ to invoke all of jQuery's native functions.

Comment: I can't get either of those to work.  They give the error `TypeError: $(...).on is not a function`.  The same happens when I substitute the `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: It looks like you are right regarding the DOM elements not being available though.  They are generated by Javascript which is inserted after my code.

Comment: Are you using the core version of jQuery packaged with Joomla or adding your own?

Comment: Standard Joomla version v1.11.1

Comment: I tried wrapping your suggested code within the IIFE but I still get the "TypeError: $(...).on is not a function" error.  I notice the site is using Mootools - could there be a clash?

Comment: Definitely, that's why i suggested the IIEF, can u update your post with the full JavaScript you currently have?

Comment: I found a way to inject my code at a later stage, after the DOM for the tabs has been created and it now works.  Your insight that the DOM elements weren't available was the root cause of my problem, so I've marked this as the correct answer.  Thanks very much for your help!